# Define a required attribute for <declare-stylable>

Tags: android, xml, custom-controls, custom-component

Is it possible to define the stylable attributes as **required**? (as in XSD schemas)

```
<declare-styleable name="PieChart">
    <attr name="name" format="string" use="required"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

The above XML does not work, is there another syntax to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

What if you throw exception in your constructor in case the attr value is null?

Comment: That would not warn me while writing the XML file, I am looking for a static solution. Although it would help during runtime.